# Strategy for updating a single user blog's content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a blogs model, what is a good strategy for updating my blog posts?

I wouldn't want to have a sign in button, because I'm the only one who will ever sign in. Would I make a resource that isn't navigable from the root that's authenticated with a key? That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up authentication, even if it's only for you. There are a lot of libraries to support this (Devise, Omniauth) and it will give your better control over what people can and can't do on your site.

That said, one solution would be to use HTTP basic authentication (included with Rails). Try something like this in your posts controller:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'your_name', password: 'password', only: :new
```

This will require a username and password for the 'posts#new' action only. Replace these values with environmental variables if you plan to open-source the codebase.

This is a really simple solution, supporting your use case but not any more complex requirements.